# Error in Android App, JNI detects error in application. Expects a constructor but void

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have been put in charge of modifying an existing android App that was created by a third party company some years ago. As you might expect I am having issues with getting the source code compiled and working. The ultimate aim is to make a new version of the app for a different region.

While I have been given this job my coding expertise is with Python Matlab etc not Java and I am struggling to fix the issues as its outside my expertise, (back end, data processing, etc).

I can get the app to compile and run on the emulator, previous posts here have been very helpful but when I make a request that involves c code the app will crash.

The app is a tidal app that uses C code to calculate tidal elevations and currents. It does this using NDK and JNI, the current error message is very long so I will try and post what is hopefully the relevant bit....

```
07-26 09:20:09.307 3730-3730/com.noc.anytide A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: expected a constructor but void com.noc.anytide.POLPredict$POLPredictResult.populateResult(double[], float, long, long): 0x86aac464
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     in call to NewObjectV
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from com.noc.anytide.POLPredict$POLPredictResult com.noc.anytide.POLPredict.POLPredictShim(double, int, long[], long[], long[], double, int, int, int, float, long, int)
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x7488b000 self=0xa990b400
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   | sysTid=3730 nice=1 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xadc5d534
```

The java file that this relates to is below:

```
package com.noc.anytide;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class POLPredict {

    public static double duration = (10f * 24f);
    public static int nvals = 400;
    public static long offset;
    public static float maxY;
    public static double currentHeight, prevHeight, nextHeight;
    public static boolean rising;
    public static boolean dataClippedLeft = false;
    public static boolean dataClippedRight = false;

    private native POLPredictResult POLPredictShim(double duration, int nvals, long Hi[], long Gi[], long Ki[], double ref_height, int Base_dd, int Base_mm, int Base_yy,
            float startTime, long startDateTime, int constit_count);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("POLPredict");
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public static String unixToString(long timestamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    public class POLPredictResult {
        public List<Number> result;
        public List<Number> dates;
        public int numVals;

        public void populateResult(double resultArray[], float maxRange, long startDateTime, long interval) {
            result = new ArrayList<Number>();
            dates = new ArrayList<Number>();
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long prevTime = currentTime - 1800000;
            long nextTime = currentTime + 1800000;
            boolean containsCurrentTide = false;
            maxY = 0.0f;
            numVals = resultArray.length;
            boolean valid = false;
            boolean partiallyValid = false;
            long pStart = 0;
            long pEnd = 0;

            long endDataTime = (startDateTime + (interval * numVals));

            if(startDateTime <= currentTime && endDataTime >= currentTime) {
                containsCurrentTide = true;
            } else {
                currentHeight = -1.0;
            }

            dataClippedLeft = false;
            dataClippedRight = false;

            if(BookMarksHandler.isNL) {
                valid = true;
            } else {
                for(int i=0;i<InAppPurchasing.tidalPurchases.size();i++) {
                    long s = InAppPurchasing.tidalPurchases.get(i).start;
                    long e = InAppPurchasing.tidalPurchases.get(i).end;
                    if(InAppPurchasing.tidalPurchases.get(i).purchased ) {
                        if(startDateTime > s && endDataTime < e) {
                            valid = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        if((startDateTime > s && startDateTime < e) || (endDataTime > s && endDataTime < e)){
                            partiallyValid = true;
                            pStart = s;
                            pEnd = e;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            boolean wroteLevel = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < numVals; i++) {
                if(!valid && !partiallyValid && ((currentTime - (12*3600000) > startDateTime) || (currentTime + (12*3600000) < startDateTime))) {
                    if(wroteLevel) {
                        dataClippedRight = true; 
                    } else {
                        dataClippedLeft = true;
                    }
                    this.result.add(-10.0);
                } else if(partiallyValid) {
                    if(startDateTime > pStart && startDateTime < pEnd) {
                        this.result.add((Number) resultArray[i]);
                        wroteLevel = true;
                    } else {
                        if(wroteLevel) {
                            dataClippedRight = true; 
                        } else {
                            dataClippedLeft = true;
                        }
                        this.result.add(-10.0);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.result.add((Number) resultArray[i]);
                    wroteLevel = true;
                }
                if(containsCurrentTide && startDateTime < currentTime) {
                    currentHeight = (double) Math.round(resultArray[i] * 100) / 100;
                }
                if(containsCurrentTide && startDateTime < prevTime) {
                    prevHeight = (double) Math.round(resultArray[i] * 100) / 100;
                }
                if(containsCurrentTide && startDateTime < nextTime) {
                    nextHeight = (double) Math.round(resultArray[i] * 100) / 100;
                }
                this.dates.add(startDateTime);
                startDateTime += interval;
            }

            maxY = maxRange;

            if(nextHeight > prevHeight) rising=true;
            else rising = false;
        }

        public void populateCurrentResult(double resultArray[], float maxRange, long startDateTime, long interval) {

            result = new ArrayList<Number>();
            dates = new ArrayList<Number>();
            for (int i = 0; i <  resultArray.length; i++) {
                this.result.add((Number) resultArray[i]);
                this.dates.add(startDateTime);
                startDateTime += interval;
            }
        }
    }

    public POLPredictResult POLPredictGo(double duration, int nvals, long Hi[], long Gi[], long Ki[], double ref_height, int Base_dd, int Base_mm, int Base_yy, float startTime, long unixStartTime, int constit_count) {

        return POLPredictShim(duration, nvals, Hi, Gi, Ki, ref_height, Base_dd, Base_mm, Base_yy, startTime, unixStartTime, constit_count);
    }
}
```

Is there anything obvious that stands out as potentially being an issue or the cause of the error message? Is there anything that springs to mind with JNI and NDK libraries dating from say 2015 being used in the present day that is likely to cause issues?

I appreciate its a big ask, but some pointers and typical reasons for this problem/error would be very helpful.

Comment: So where is the code for `POLPredictShim` (i.e. the C code)?

Comment: This is what is confusing me, I wasn't sure what POLPredictShim refers too as there is no C code with that name. There is a JNIShim.c file that I am trying to figure out which I think maybe related.

Comment: A simple file content search should suffice for finding the correct source file.

Comment: Can you confirm what this line means? "private native POLPredictResult POLPredictShim(double duration, int nvals, long Hi[], long Gi[], long Ki[], double ref_height, int Base_dd, int Base_mm, int Base_yy,
            float startTime, long startDateTime, int constit_count);"

Comment: I know what the private and native mean but the POLPredictResult followed by POLPredictShim is confusing me. I am reading the tutorials on JNI but have not figured it out yet.

Comment: It just how you state that you're providing a function named `Java_com_noc_anytide_POlPredict_POLPredictShim` in some native library that will return a `POLPredictResult` Java object.

Comment: Brill, thank you. I can't find this function which I think may be the issue. Is the function named in the JNICALL part of a c file? POLPredictShim is mentioned here but nowhere else.